# Move woo commerce reviews from tabs

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, genesis

I have been trying to move woocommerce reviews. I was able to remove the reviews and replace them outside of the tab, but I am having trouble getting the form for the review to show up.

This is the code I have so far:

```
function woocommerce_review_list() {

$args = array ('post_type' => 'product');
    $comments = get_comments( $args );
    wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'woocommerce_comments' ), $comments);

}
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_review_list', 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try loading WooCommerce's entire comments template:

```
wc_get_template('single-product-reviews.php');
```

Or failing that you could simply copy out the relevant parts from [that template](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/content-single-product.php).